# Getting a PID from a Background Process Run as Another User

Tags: bash, pid, su

Getting a background process ID is easy to do from the prompt by going:

```
$ my_daemon &
$ echo $!
```

But what if I want to run it as a different user like:

```
su - joe -c "/path/to/my_daemon &;"
```

Now how can I capture the PID of my_daemon?

Comment: This looks solidly on-topic for SO to me; it is a question about shell programming, and as such is within the remit of SO.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Succinctly - with a good deal of difficulty.

You have to arrange for the su'd shell to write the child PID to a file and then pick the output.  Given that it will be 'joe' creating the file and not 'dex', that adds another layer of complexity.

The simplest solution is probably:

```
su - joe -c "/path/to/my_daemon & echo \$! > /tmp/su.joe.$$"
bg=$(</tmp/su.joe.$$)
rm -f /tmp/su.joe.$$   # Probably fails - joe owns it, dex does not
```

The next solution involves using a spare file descriptor - number 3.

```
su - joe -c "/path/to/my_daemon 3>&- & echo \$! 1>&3" 3>/tmp/su.joe.$$
bg=$(</tmp/su.joe.$$)
rm -f /tmp/su.joe.$$
```

If you're worried about interrupts etc (and you probably should be), then you trap things too:

```
tmp=/tmp/su.joe.$$
trap "rm -f $tmp; exit 1" 0 1 2 3 13 15
su - joe -c "/path/to/my_daemon 3>&- & echo \$! 1>&3" 3>$tmp
bg=$(<$tmp)
rm -f $tmp
trap 0 1 2 3 13 15
```

(The caught signals are HUP, INT, QUIT, PIPE and TERM - plus 0 for shell exit.)

Warning: nice theory - untested code...

Comment: Awesome answer. I might be able to get by with just this: `su - joe -c "/path/to/my_daemon & echo \$! > /tmp/su.joe.$$"` escaping the $! and no semi-colon after the `my_daemon &` are certainly gotchas too. I'm going to play around with it a little bit.

Comment: Be sure to add a space after the $! or the shell may interpret this weirdly.

Answer (score 1):

The approaches presented here didn't work for me.  Here's what I did:

```
PID_FILE=/tmp/service_pid_file
su -m $SERVICE_USER -s /bin/bash -c "/path/to/executable $ARGS >/dev/null 2>&1 & echo \$! >$PID_FILE"
PID=`cat $PID_FILE`
```

Answer (score 1):

As long as the output from the background process is redirected, you can send the PID to stdout:

```
su "${user}" -c "${executable} > '${log_file}' 2>&1 & echo \$!"
```

The PID can then be redirected to a file owned by the first user, rather than the second user.

```
su "${user}" -c "${executable} > '${log_file}' 2>&1 & echo \$!" > "${pid_file}"
```

The log files do need to be owned by the second user to do it this way, though.

Answer (score -1):

Here's my solution

```
su oracle -c "/home/oracle/database/runInstaller" &
pid=$(pgrep -P $!)
```

Explantation

- `pgrep -P $!` - Gets the child process of the parent pid `$!`

Comment: Why is this downvoted? Two lines of succinct code without use of tmp files.

Answer (score -1):

I took the above solution by Linux, but had to add a sleep to give the child process a chance to start.

```
su - joe -c "/path/to/my_daemon > /some/output/file" &
parent=$!
sleep 1
pid=$(pgrep -P $parent)
```

Running in bash, it doesn't like `pid=$(pgrep -P $!)` but if I add a space after the `!` it's ok: `pid=$(pgrep -P $! )`. I stuck with the extra `$parent` variable to remind myself what I'm doing next time I look at the script.